# Raise Flag for a [Penalty Box]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, flags, account-suspension

### Edit on Point

> Not talking about having someone **pushed off** the site for a long period. My terminolgy is wrong (I'm new here). Penalty Box is more like what I was talking about. Will try to edit the rest of the content to reflect.
>
> I would retract if I could because the topic obviously hits a raw nerve. But this is meta, So I'll **cop** it. But I do state that not one single answer took the time to realize that I was talking about **categorizing** the flags to be more succinct.

Okay, to start that title does seem to match anything similar or did my searching but this may (well probably) have been raised before.

This comes out of my recent experience regarding this question (if it's still there):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122837/how-to-create-an-efficient-scalable-multi-tenant-data-layer-using-mongodb

For background, as the question had come up, I could see from the content that this was not going to be asking a specific question that could be handled within the guidlines of posting on the site. As such I did what I think is right and flagged the question for close.

Now also believing I was right in doing so, I posted a comment to the question pointing out that it was likely to be considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) with the appropriate link, encouraging them to to look at the guide. What followed was **not** what I would call appreciation for giving someone a heads up that their question was likely to go away.

So resulting from this the OP clearly "took offence" (take a look if you can, It makes interesting reading at least), but at the time at least I had not paid any attention to the comments they were posting but it seemed likely that it wasn't going to stop.

This is the point where I thought, "Hey, better flag this for a moderator", and went to submit the flag. And this is where my point is. What was clear to me (and I wasn't expecting an immediate result at all) was that the OP was going to continue their rant, believing they had been subject to a personal attack. So I thought it in the best interests to notify a moderator and **flag** that the OP may be in need of a temporary suspension. At least to allow them some time to **cool off** and consider the actions they had taken.

So I did raise the flag, but of course, the only **appropriate** option that seemed available was to select **other**. This is really where I am at in this question, because I don't believe I am wrong that the **other bin** as it were is by nature subject to not being the main focus of attention as it would require reading through the reason for the flag and then considering it in terms of why it was raised and if it was reasonable.

This leads to the direct question of "Should there be a standard option to suggest a supension?", or specifically as I was asking a "cooling off period". And not having it available leads me to wonder how many of these situations roll away without the **"mod"** really getting to see the behavior of the user.

As it is, there is a lot more commentary on that question, from other users who have actively discouraged the actions. And the message may have sunk in to some point. But I don't at this stage see it likely the OP will either edit or remove their question by their own accord.

So you can't really be sure that someone got the point. And as for the **flag**, I'm left wondering if given the type for the submission it is just something that disappears into the ether.

Does anyone else think this would be a useful thing? Indeed also feel free to comment and/or respond if you believe my approach was right or wrong / inflammatory or reasoned.

Just trying to come to a point for something that is of benefit to everyone.

### Note

The question mentioned was significantly down-voted, but not by me. My only actions were related to bringing the attention to the off-topic nature to encourage the OP to change their question to something more appropriate.

Comment: Voting on Meta signals agreement with the idea you are proposing; they don't think this should be implemented.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Again thanks for actually reading. You know I kind of get it which is why the question is here in the first place. BTW The edit history on your answer rpoves my point. You reacted. You didn't read.

Comment: Can you drop the assumptions, please? I am responding to your comment here, not your post. You marked this as a feature request, and voting reflects how people view the feature.

Comment: @MartijnPieters honestly because I hoped **meta** was a forum for discussion but it seems to be another arena for personal attack. Read all the responses including yours. It's not an opinion on a feature, you just said **No you cant do that, moderators do that**. And every response is the same.

Comment: @NeilLunn no. You suggested something (new flag type) and users here disagree that it's really needed. End of story, no attack here.

Answer (score 9):

No, there should not be such a flag.

Temporary suspensions are something moderators decide on based on overall behaviour of a user, and is not a measure the general community can or should flag. Certainly *not* for just one post, by individual members of the community.

The right action here is to flag offensive or abusive comments as such, and walk away.  Let moderators deal with a user that continues to be offensive.  If you have noticed a pattern of behaviour in a user (beyond a single post), then an *other* flag explaining that behaviour might be appropriate.

Only after repeat behaviour and after having been warned, will a user ever be put in the penalty box. And such warnings are private. The community is generally not part of that process. See [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) for more details on what Temporary Suspensions are about; they are a last resort, not a regular occurence.

Comment: Clarifying, I am not asking to "raise the supension" myself. I was just in the line of thinking it might be a good idea to raise the point directly to the moderator reviewing. And for the record, I did walk away. You can look for yourself if the post is still there.

Comment: @NeilLunn: and why is a simple `other` flag not good enough for that?

Comment: My reasoning as I mentioned is **other** seems to be like a great big bin, as opposed to the **targeted** reasons given by the alternate selections. I may be wrong, but that is the perception.

Comment: Nope, `other` is the right way to go here. Suggesting actions to moderators to take is not a flagging reason anyway; the right thing to do is just to flag as abusive.

Comment: That wasn't my interpretation of that condition. But I'm not claiming to be an expert on that.

Comment: That's why I am trying to tell you about how this all works, normally. :-)

Comment: Then I thank you for the information. Please don't tell me that **you** have been interpreting this as an argument :)

Comment: I most definitely have not, no problem! :-)

Comment: And I thank you for that link. The terms I am using in the question are not the right ones. "Penalty Box" was more like what I was referring to. Best make that clear before I make more people angry.

Comment: @NeilLunn: Temparory suspension **is** the penalty box; the latter is a nickname, the former the official term.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time the decision to suspend involves content that is not visible to regular users. Suspensions are usually for repeated behaviour, the previous history of a user is very important there and regular users have no easy way to view it.

There would be no benefit to having a flag suggesting suspension, the community often does not have enough information to decide this.

What is important is that if you flag such a user, mention in the flag that there is a pattern of behaviour and not just a single incident. That is important information for the acting moderator.

Comment: Understand that the point was "temporary" by which I mean a day or two. Which I believed existed at the Mod discretion. But please correct me if I am wrong on that point.

Comment: @NeilLunn We generally don't bother with suspensions shorter than 7 days.

Comment: So just for learning sake, if the flag should point out that there was a pattern of behavior, then would **other** then be the appropriate flag? And as such, is it just a **junk** conception that such a category is a "bin" that gets little attention?

Comment: @neil many flag types can be handled by many users (these are handled fast) other can only be handled by mods and are slower. Certain mod only flags are given priority such as spam and offensive are given priority however **all flags are looked at and none are a "bin"**

Answer (score 1):

A decision to suspend is and should be with a mod, as such such a flag would be inappropriate.

Even ignoring that an other flag is pretty much essential for this because you're going to have to explain the situation.  A generic flag is never going to cut it. Imagine a mod recieves a "this user needs to be banned" flag; they then need to try to figure out why, read all the posts and comments, look at the profile etc. On the otherhand an "other" flag can explain the situation and then the mod can take whatever action they feel is appropriate.

Or if its relatively simple, such as an offensive comment then again just flag that. A mod will take whatever action is appropriate.

Comment: I'm actually beginning to if the whole title should have been "Is the **other** flag enough" Because that is actually my real question. And essentially to that end **how** does the moderator review history of behavior. The real point is categorization and not instant action. But I'm willing to accept I have the whole concept wrong. Just looking for some guidance.

Comment: @Neil I would not just say it's "enough" I would say its exactly right. Anything which doesn't fit into the existing flag types is going to need a freeform text box for explanation since its clearly complicated